# Show that if $E$ is a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ then $\inf(E)$ exists and belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Well by the completeness axiom since $E$ is non-empty and bounded $\sup(E)$ exists. To prove that $\inf(E)$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$ lets use the approximation property and choose an $a \in E$ such that $i \leq a \lt i + 1$. If $a = i$ then $i \in E$. Otherwise by contrapositive assume that there is no $a \in E$ S.T. $i \lt a \lt i+1$. So assume $a \lt i$. $a \lt i$. Set $\epsilon \lt a - i$ Then we get $\epsilon + i \lt a$ Therefore we get $i \lt i + \epsilon \lt a \lt i + 1$. There fore $a$ does not fall between $i, i + 1$ which means $a$ is not in $E$ and therefore a contradiction so $\inf(E) \in \mathbb{Z}$ How come I am getting no answers. Is this a bad question?

Comment: The completeness axiom is not needed for this problem, as the answer of @Davettaja shows. Just think about $\mathbb Z$ and its order.

Comment: To answer "is this a bad question": it is not exactly clear what you are asking. It seems like you want a proof of the assertion in the title, but you seem to give one in the question body. So do you want a simpler proof, or for someone to verify your proof? Moreover, the body of your question is quite messy: there are no line breaks, and punctuation is missing. It's also preferable to restate your problem in the question body if you've written it in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Bounded subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is finite and hence has a minimum. The infimum must be the minimum which is an integer.